# Why does Thorin tell Bilbo that he has "keen eyes"?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, desolation-of-smaug

In the second film why does Thorin think Bilbo has keen eyes? Bilbo finds a mountain sized dwarf carved into a mountain that they are all standing next to and for some reason Thorin thinks it means Bilbo has amazing eyes. Why is this? Are dwarves blind? Why can't any of them see it - seeing as how they all come from this mountain anyway - surely one of them would have noticed it before in the 100 or so years that they were living there. It is also a clear as day to the viewer of the film.

Comment: There is no mountain-sized carved dwarf in The Hobbit.

Comment: I'm still rereading the books so I'm not 100% sure, but in the original books, Bilbo is supposed to be the burglar of the group. It's a recurring theme that the dwarves refer to capabilities that Bilbo may or may not have that one would associate with a burglar.

Comment: Surely only Thorin Okenshield actually came from the Lonely Mountain?

Comment: @Mast There is an explicit scene (in Mirkwood, when they come to the river and need to get the boat) in the book where Bilbo is acknowledged as having the sharpest eyesight. Having skipped that episode in the movie, they may have tried to insert a similar line elsewhere (in line with Sava's answer).

Comment: @jamesqf They put that scene in the movie. Thorin and party find a giant dwarf carved on the side of the mountain and Bilbo realizes that the relief on the sculpture is actually the stairs to the top where the keyhole is.

Comment: @jamesqf This is about the film

Comment: @chepner: earlier, in the first or second chapter, it is explained that Bilbo has keen eyes and is extremely good at aiming. It is said that he was very good at hunting rabbits with rocks when he was younger.

Answer (score 59):

Thorin doesn't tell Bilbo that he has keen eyes because Bilbo found the giant carved dwarf, but rather because he found the secret stairs that led to the top of the dwarf and thus to where the secret keyhole is located.

Comment: Yes, to be precise, he is the only one to remark that the decoration pattern in counter-relief on the sculpure is designed as a stair. The tree hiding the forest, kind of